# Getting the masked URL values in Mediawiki

Tags: php, apache, htaccess, mod-rewrite, mediawiki

I have successfully masked the URL in Mediawiki. By using the following scripts in *.htaccess* and `localsettings.php` files in Mediawiki, i.e.:

**.htaccess**:

```
Options +FollowSymLinks

RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d

RewriteRule ^(.*)/(.*)$ /mediawiki/index.php?title=$1&actions=$2 [L]
```

**Localsettings.php**:

```
$wgScriptPath       = "/lib/mediawiki";
$wgArticlePath      = "/lib/mediawiki/$1/$2";
```

It is working fine with required URL. But my problem is I want to consider the second parameter as a querystring for my pages. But I could not get the second parameter in my file. I tried with `$wgrequest` function but it is only giving the first parameter as `title`. I tried with `$_REQUEST` also, it is sometimes give the value of `$_REQUEST['actions']`. But many times not. I cant understand what is the problem.

Answer (score 2):

I will start by saying you should not use `$_REQUEST` for something like this, it grabs not only from the URL string, but depending on how it is set up it can grab from `$_POST` data and `$_COOKIE` data, which means it is a bit of a security risk.

I would suggest you use the `$_GET` variable (`$_GET['actions']`) as you are grabbing it from the URL and I would test it against times when you know actions is either set or not set.

I would imagine that what might be happening is URLs are being accessed that do not have this parameter set in them, this is based on the fact your `.htaccess` file looks fine. In this case what I would suggest is that you have some sort of default action set up for when it is blank.

```
$actions = isset($_GET['actions']) ? $_GET['actions'] : 'my_default_action';
```

You would also want  to throw some security into this to not trust anything from `$_GET` until you have cleaned it up or whitelisted it somehow.